# Network Hardware priority with C++ and MQ

Tags: c++, hardware, ibm-mq, transmission

I am working on a proof of concept where some data as to be sent to a remote queue in WebSphere MQ. The PC's that will be running the client software will be Windows and will have access to Wi-Fi, satellite and cellular data transmission.

Since there is a different cost associated to each mode of transmission, the client wants us to pick the lowest costing available transmission hardware in real time. By this I mean we will be sending our data with Wi-Fi, cellular transmission or satellite, in order of availability.

My problem is that windows seems to be picking the hardware used for transmission. From what I have seen in the MQ c++ library there is no way for me to specify which hardware should be used to transmit. I know this can be done outside of MQ but as anyone been able to do this within MQ?

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, each of these routes has a different IP address.  If that is the case, you can use a Client Channel Definition Table file.  When defining the `CLNTCONN` channels, use the [`LOCLADDR` attribute](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaj.doc/sc11040_.htm) to bind the channel to the appropriate IP address.  You can either use three different CCDT files and select the right one at run time, or you can put all three channels in the same CCDT file.  IF you use a single CCDT file, it will be necessary to use generic names for the `QMNAME` field.  For example, for the WiFi channel, use `QMNAME(WIFI)` and use `QMNAME(SAT)` for satellite.  Then at run time use [generic QMgr names](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaf.doc/cs12740_.htm) `*SAT` or `*WIFI` in your `CONNECT` call.